# How filter pivot table results to exclude rows containing certain words

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

On a daily basis a transaction file is created containing about 25,000 rows of data.

The relevant fields included are Account number, Activity, Description, Value

Relevant Activity options are "Deposit", "Deposit Security"; there are dozens of other values that are ignored

The Description field content varies from day to day as it is unique to each transaction. When a transaction Description contains "ITRO" or "ITRI" it indicates a transaction that needs to be ignored. There is a ton of additional data after those acronyms and it varies per transaction, per day

I have a pivot table that grabs only those transactions that match the account number, activity and value criteria, no problem. What I can't figure out is how to add a pivot table filter that will exclude transactions where the Description field contains either ITRO or ITRI.

I could manually sort and delete these rows. The issue is that this template is used by a rotating group of entry level employees who don't understand excel well enough to do this so they paste the new transactions each day into the template and refresh the pivot table. Yes, it should be handled programmatically; yes, there are inherent risks to this approach. It's being worked on but until that long term solution is ready I really want to make this interim solution as close to the long term solution.

Thanks!

It works fine if I enter just ITRO or just ITRI. I can't figure out how to enter it so excel sees it as OR.

[image]